# API route gives 404 error: Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I was testing my api on godaddy server. But due to some reasons the route is not working and giving 404 error

In order to make sure that the route exists...I tested it like using below code.

```
$routeCollection = \Route::getRoutes();

foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    echo $value->getPath();
}
```

and you can check the same here as well: http://pankajservers.in/ when u type any thing in user name or password and when u see console...it will show u 404 api error and on local it works perfectly.

**JQuery**

```
var data = {
    "EmailAddress": $("input[name='EmailAddress']").val(), 
    "Password":     $("input[name='Password']").val(),
    "_token":       "{{ csrf_token() }}"
};
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url:    "{!! route('AuthenticateUser') !!}",
    cache:  false,
    async:  true,
    data:   data,
    success: function(result) {
        return false;
    },
    error: function(result) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://pankajservers.in/api/v1/AuthenticateUser" 
    accept-charset="UTF-8" 
    id="loginForm">

    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="GtSNw3bgzFO6jwi8IVFWnvymd2e8EqIXkAhPtPxb">

    <input class="form-control" name="EmailAddress" type="text">

    <input class="form-control" name="Password" type="password" value="">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>
```

**POST Route**

```
Route::post('/AuthenticateUser', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  'API\UserManagement\Auth\Login\apiLoginController@AuthenticateUser', 
        'as'   =>  'AuthenticateUser'
    )
);
```

**Route Service Provider**

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    'prefix' => 'api/v1',
], function ($router) {
    require base_path('routes/API/UserManagement/Auth/Login/Login.php');
});
```

Comment: could you post your prefix for that route too.  It looks like there is no prefix called `api/v1`

Comment: Added the `RouteServiceProvider` Code. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: have you tried to use `php artisan route:list` to check whether the route with your prefix exists there?

Comment: Check the first code block in my question and as the proof you can see the route list in page header here: http://pankajservers.in/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you have a rewrite issue. I tried going to the route on your site, but I prepended `/index.php` to the route path. That threw a Laravel method exception, which is expected when you visit a POST-only route. Here, check it out:

http://pankajservers.in/index.php/api/v1/AuthenticateUser

I'm not sure whether you're using Nginx or Apache, but I suspect either the Nginx config or the Apache .htaccess isn't quite right.

**EDIT:**

Take a look at Laravel's installation documentation. There's a section about rewrite configuration that might give you some insight:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#web-server-configuration

Comment: it works perfectly, How can i fix this rewrite issue in godaddy server? +1

Comment: Do you know whether your server uses Nginx or Apache?

Comment: I was missing .htaccess file in public folder/

Answer (score 7):

All API requests must be prefixed as '/api/' in your ajax requests.

```
Ex: http://example.local/api/items
```

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve by changing `'prefix' => 'api/v1'`, to `'prefix' => 'v1'`,

as in laravel `api` is assumed in the url of `api.php` route.